# Как создать функцию, что создает данные для записи в файл csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Эта функция должна создавать и возвращать список длины n внутренних списков длинны m (таблица с n строк и m столбцов). Числа n и m выбираются случайно в диапазоне от 3 до 10. В таблицу записывать значения только 0 или 1. Заголовка у таблицы нет.
Я написал следующий код:

```
def create_random_list_csv(min=3, max=10):
    new_list = [[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(random.randint(3,10))]for _ in range(random.randint(3,10))]
    return new_list
```

Но он возвращает список списков, а не таблицу. Как это исправить? Может разбить на несколько функций?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
m = random.randint(3, 10)
n = random.randint(3, 10)

new_list = [[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
```

в вашем коде для каждого элемента списка вычисляется новый (случайный) размер вложенного списка, поэтому и не получается таблица

вычислите размеры заранее и не парьтесь